# PHP - URL with querystring with "&" in XML

Tags: php, xml, query-string

I have a small problem with dynamicly creating "sitemap.xml". The problem is that the XML is deleting the "&" character in LOC

Here my code, that creats the r

```
$this->myfullurl."?id=".$id."&name=".urlencode($name);
```

Any ideas how i can solve this problem?

Comment: What is *LOC*? In programming it's a common abbrevation for [Lines Of Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) but I guess that is not what you mean. would be nice if you could clarify this. Also from your question it's not clear how XML can delete something - XML is just something, it can not perform any actions. So please review your question and improve it, looks like some code is missing and also some words are abruptly broken etc. - Also it's not clear to me why you should be the first who asks about this on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Answer (score 3):

Change the `&` to `&amp;` which is the appropriate format for xml entities.

Answer (score 1):

XML uses HTML entities, so change the string to this:

```
$this->myfullurl."?id=".$id."&amp;name=".urlencode($name);
```